# child views losing layout_margin

Tags: android, layoutparams

I'm adding a LinearLayout as a child of a custom layout. The LinearLayout has margins, but the margins never get into the LayoutParams.

Here's the xml for the LinearLayout

```
<com.perinote.widgets.LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/popup_margin_LR"
  android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/popup_margin_LR"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/popup_margin_TB"
  android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/popup_margin_TB"
  >
```

Here's the code that inflates and adds the LinearLayout to the custom layout, where "this" is the custom layout, which is an extension of `ViewGroup`:

```
  public View setContentView (int layoutId)
  {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate (layoutId, this, false);
    contentView = v;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams ();
    this.addView (contentView, params);

    return contentView;
  }
```

And, finally, here's a piece of onMeasure in the custom layout.

```
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
  {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) contentView.getLayoutParams();

    int contentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize (widthMeasureSpec);
    int contentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize (heightMeasureSpec);

    ... some other stuff ...

    // measure contentView.
    int contentWidthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec (contentWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int contentHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec (contentHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    contentView.measure (contentWidthSpec, contentHeightSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension (MeasureSpec.getSize (widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.getSize (heightMeasureSpec));
  }
```

The app crashes on the first line of `onMeasure()` -- `params =`. The error is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
```

which indicates that, during inflation, the inflator created LayoutParams instead of MarginLayoutParams.

What can I do to get MarginLayoutParms or some other variant that includes the layout_margin values?

Comment: You'll need to override `generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet)` and return a `MarginLayoutParams` object, be it a direct instance, or one of your own custom subclass. You might have a look at [the source for `FrameLayout`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/FrameLayout.java), as it's a nice, simple example to follow when creating your own `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Btw, unless you need some markedly different behavior than any of the existing `ViewGroup`s provide, it's usually easier to subclass one of those, rather than extending `ViewGroup` itself.

Comment: That was exactly right. Even more, Google documented this and I missed it. Thanks so much for responding. If you post an "answer", I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Oh, hi, there. I didn't notice that you'd edited your comment. If you're referring to the "don't use `ViewGroup` directly" suggestion, it's cool. We'll just call it a freebie :-) You could either delete this, or feel free to post your own answer with the implementation that you end up using. Thanks, though, for the offer. I appreciate it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The class extending `ViewGroup` must also override `generateLayoutParams()`. In my case:

```
@Override
public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams (AttributeSet attrs)
{
  return new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams (getContext(), attrs);
}
```

but you can extend `LayoutParams` to contain whatever you need instead of using `MarginLayoutParams`. During inflation of a child view, `generateLayoutParams()` gets called. This (aha) is why inflate needs to know the parent view group, even if you aren't adding the new child to the parent at this time.

Credit really goes to @Mike M. Thanks!